# How could I draw a RGB HBITMAP and display it in a STATIC WINDOW using C?

Tags: c, windows

```
HBITMAP DisplayMap(HDC hThisDC){
    HDC hDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hThisDC);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    bi.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth=670;
    bi.biHeight=540;
    bi.biPlanes=1;
    bi.biBitCount=24;
    bi.biCompression=BI_RGB;
    int lineSize=((((bi.biWidth*bi.biBitCount)+31)&~31)>>3);
    bi.biSizeImage=lineSize*bi.biHeight;

    unsigned char* data=(unsigned char*)malloc(bi.biSizeImage);
    int off=0;
    for(int y=0;y<bi.biHeight;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<bi.biWidth;x++){
            data[off+3*x]=255;
            data[off+3*x+1]=0;
            data[off+3*x+2]=127;
        }
        off+=lineSize;
    }

    HBITMAP hBitmap=CreateDIBitmap(hDC,&bi,CBM_INIT,data,(BITMAPINFO*)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    SetDIBits(hDC,hBitmap,0,bi.biHeight,data,(BITMAPINFO*)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    return hBitmap;
}

//
HBITMAP hBitmap=DisplayMap(GetDC(hwnd));
if(hBitmap==NULL||true){
    char* str=(char*)malloc(15);
    sprintf(str,"ERROR: %d!",GetLastError());
    MessageBox(NULL,str,"ALERT",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}

ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);
SendMessage(hFrame, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
//
```

If I use "(HBITMAP)LoadImage()" to display it, it shows no problem. But as I'm using my function "DisplayMap()" which is supposed to create a HBITMAP out of nothing it doesn't work. The script shows no erros and the "hBitmap" return a valid HBITMAP (not NULL), but don't matter the color I choose to fill the bitmap, it keeps displaying the same full-black image.

I searched for a solution in Google through many sources and I wasn't able to figure out the problem. I thank for any help, has been a long time I don't work with c.The idea is to  create and display an image sequence which shall be generate just in time without loading anything from files.

Comment: Can you explain `if(hBitmap==NULL||true)`?

Comment: Possibly you need to use `CreateDIBSection` instead of `CreateDIBitmap`. The latter *assumes* your DC properties are indeed the one you are filling in.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you GetDC from hwnd, but STM_SETIMAGE to hFrame. Try GetDC from hFrame.

Comment: I recently tried with: "HBITMAP hBitmap=DisplayMap(GetDC(hFrame));". Thanks for your help, I think it makes more sense with "hFrame", but it couldn't solve the problem, the image kept coming fully black and it shouldn't be like this.